# Conditional Join based on user input

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am making an SSRS report and am allowing for user input on the decision to join two tables. If they select `No(0)`, then this query runs:

```
select distinct case when book.PROPCODE = '00' then 'R6' else book.PROPCODE end as PROPCODE,
       BKNAME,
       BKARRIVE,
       BKDEPART,
       BKRMNUM,
       book.BOOKID
from NGFMBOOK book
inner join NGFMBOOK2 on ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(Uniqueid2,'/','0'),'-',0))) =  ltrim(rtrim(str(book.BOOKID)))
where BKARRIVE between @StartDate and @EndDate
and book.PROPCODE in (@PropCode)
Order By BookID
```

If they select `Yes(1)` then an additional join is added to the query :

```
select distinct case when book.PROPCODE = '00' then 'R6' else book.PROPCODE end as PROPCODE,
       BKNAME,
       BKARRIVE,
       BKDEPART,
       BKRMNUM,
       book.BOOKID
from NGFMBOOK book
inner join NGFMBOOK2 on ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(Uniqueid2,'/','0'),'-',0))) =  ltrim(rtrim(str(book.BOOKID)))
inner join [RPV1Data\RPV1Data].RP_V1Data.dbo.NGFUNCT func ON book.BOOKID = func.BOOKID --this is the extra join
where BKARRIVE between @StartDate and @EndDate
and book.PROPCODE in (@PropCode)
Order By BookID
```

Is there a way to have a Case statement or something similar so that I don't have to have two completely different queries? I am trying

```
set @queryHeader = 'select distinct case when book.PROPCODE = ''00'' then ''R6'' else book.PROPCODE end as PROPCODE, BKNAME, BKARRIVE, BKDEPART, BKRMNUM, book.BOOKID from NGFMBOOK book inner join NGFMBOOK2 on ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(Uniqueid2,''/'',''0''),''-'',0))) =  ltrim(rtrim(str(book.BOOKID)))'
set @option1 = 'inner join NGFMBOOK2 on ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(Uniqueid2,''/'',''0''),''-'',0))) =  ltrim(rtrim(str(book.BOOKID)))'
set @option2 = 'inner join NGFMBOOK2 on ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(Uniqueid2,''/'',''0''),''-'',0))) =  ltrim(rtrim(str(book.BOOKID))) inner join [RPV1Data\RPV1Data].RP_V1Data.dbo.NGFUNCT func ON book.BOOKID = func.BOOKID'
set @queryFooter = 'where BKARRIVE between @StartDate and @EndDate and book.PROPCODE in (@PropCode) Order By BookID'
set @query = @queryHeader + case when @SearchFun = 1 then @option2 else @option1 end + @queryFooter

exec(@query)
```

But that is giving me an error (Incorrect syntax near 'BKARRIVE')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say your parameter where the user is selecting Yes(1)/No(0) is @parameter . then just add @parameter = 1 in your 2nd join condition so when yes is selected in the @parameter that join will execute with valid data else it wil. I have not tested the query but logically it should work for you.

```
select distinct case when book.PROPCODE = '00' then 'R6' else book.PROPCODE end as PROPCODE,
           BKNAME,
           BKARRIVE,
           BKDEPART,
           BKRMNUM,
           book.BOOKID
    from NGFMBOOK book
    inner join NGFMBOOK2 on ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(Uniqueid2,'/','0'),'-',0))) =  ltrim(rtrim(str(book.BOOKID)))
    left join [RPV1Data\RPV1Data].RP_V1Data.dbo.NGFUNCT func ON book.BOOKID = func.BOOKID AND @parameter = 1 --this is the extra join
    where BKARRIVE between @StartDate and @EndDate
    and book.PROPCODE in (@PropCode)
    and ((func.BOOKID IS NOT NULL and @parameter = 1) 
    OR @parameter = 0)
    Order By BookID
```

Comment: That does work if @SearchFun = 1 (that's what I was using already instead of @paremeter). However if it is 0 then my query returns nothing.

Comment: I updated it with left join and another condition in where clause. Can you check if it works?

Comment: Missed the extra and clause. Now I get the 7 that I want if SearchFun is 1, but 0 if SearchFun is 0 (should get 51 back).

Comment: how about now? I added one more OR condition.

Comment: Booyakasha! That did the trick. Gonna take some studying to figure out how you did what you did though...

Answer (score 0):

Use a space before the where clause

```
    set @queryFooter = ' where BKARRIVE between @StartDate and @EndDate and book.PROPCODE in (@PropCode) Order By BookID'
```

Use a select @query to see your created statement before executing it

```
Declare @queryHeader nvarchar(1000),
@option1 nvarchar(1000),@option2 nvarchar(1000),@queryFooter nvarchar(500),@query nvarchar(max),@SearchFun int
set @SearchFun=1

set @queryHeader = 'select distinct case when book.PROPCODE = ''00'' then ''R6'' else book.PROPCODE end as PROPCODE, BKNAME, BKARRIVE, BKDEPART, BKRMNUM, book.BOOKID from NGFMBOOK book inner join NGFMBOOK2 on ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(Uniqueid2,''/'',''0''),''-'',0))) =  ltrim(rtrim(str(book.BOOKID)))'
set @option1 = 'inner join NGFMBOOK2 on ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(Uniqueid2,''/'',''0''),''-'',0))) =  ltrim(rtrim(str(book.BOOKID)))'
set @option2 = 'inner join NGFMBOOK2 on ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(Uniqueid2,''/'',''0''),''-'',0))) =  ltrim(rtrim(str(book.BOOKID))) inner join [RPV1Data\RPV1Data].RP_V1Data.dbo.NGFUNCT func ON book.BOOKID = func.BOOKID'
set @queryFooter = ' where BKARRIVE between @StartDate and @EndDate and book.PROPCODE in (@PropCode) Order By BookID'
set @query = @queryHeader + case when @SearchFun = 1 then @option2 else @option1 end + @queryFooter


select @query
```